# why is chef recipe run twice?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a very basic recipe right now.

```
include_recipe 'apache2'

Chef::Log.info(node[:inewebapp][:apache]);
node[:inewebapp][:apache].each do |vhost|
  Chef::Log.info("Currently on host #{vhost['docroot_dir']}");
end
```

I'm trying to figure out - while building this with test kitchen - do I get log messages like my recipe is being run multiple times?

This is the output of `kitchen converge server`

```
   Installing Cookbook Gems:
   Compiling Cookbooks...
   /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/hostsfile/resources/entry.rb:35: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
   [2017-07-19T15:36:05+00:00] INFO: [{"docroot_dir"=>"/var/www/host1", "server_name"=>"host1"}, {"docroot_dir"=>"/var/www/host2", "server_name"=>"host2"}]
   [2017-07-19T15:36:05+00:00] INFO: [{"docroot_dir"=>"/var/www/host1", "server_name"=>"host1"}, {"docroot_dir"=>"/var/www/host2", "server_name"=>"host2"}]
   [2017-07-19T15:36:05+00:00] INFO: Currently on host /var/www/host1
   [2017-07-19T15:36:05+00:00] INFO: Currently on host /var/www/host1
   [2017-07-19T15:36:05+00:00] INFO: Currently on host /var/www/host2
   [2017-07-19T15:36:05+00:00] INFO: Currently on host /var/www/host2
```

I have no `attributes/default.rb` file is empty and my `.kitchen.yml` looks like this

```
  ---
  driver:
    name: vagrant

  provisioner:
    name: chef_zero
    product_name: chef
    product_version: 13.0.118
    log_level: info

  verifier:
    name: inspec

  platforms:
    - name: ubuntu-16.04

  suites:
    - name: server
      run_list:
        - recipe[apt]
        - recipe[ine-webapp::apache]
      verifier:
        inspec_tests:
          - test/integration/server
      attributes:
        inewebapp:
          user: 'vagrant'
          apache:
            - docroot_dir: /var/www/host1
              server_name: host1
            - docroot_dir: /var/www/host2
              server_name: host2
```

I know my recipes should be idempotent, but I'm not sure why my recipe is being executed twice?

**Update**

After more carefully examining the output of my `kitchen converge server` it looks like multiple instances of the chef-client are being run?  still not understanding why though?

```
       Transferring files to <server-ubuntu-1604>
   [2017-07-19T15:58:59+00:00] INFO: Started chef-zero at chefzero://localhost:8889 with repository at /tmp/kitchen, /tmp/kitchen
     One version per cookbook

   [2017-07-19T15:58:59+00:00] INFO: Started chef-zero at chefzero://localhost:8889 with repository at /tmp/kitchen, /tmp/kitchen
     One version per cookbook

   [2017-07-19T15:58:59+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
   [2017-07-19T15:58:59+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
   Starting Chef Client, version 13.0.118
   [2017-07-19T15:58:59+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 13.0.118 ***
   [2017-07-19T15:58:59+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 13.0.118 ***
   [2017-07-19T15:58:59+00:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux
   [2017-07-19T15:58:59+00:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux
   [2017-07-19T15:58:59+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 14491
   [2017-07-19T15:58:59+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 14491
   [2017-07-19T15:58:59+00:00] INFO: The plugin path /etc/chef/ohai/plugins does not exist. Skipping...
   [2017-07-19T15:58:59+00:00] INFO: The plugin path /etc/chef/ohai/plugins does not exist. Skipping...
   [2017-07-19T15:59:00+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[apt]", "recipe[ine-webapp::apache]"] from CLI options
   [2017-07-19T15:59:00+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[apt]", "recipe[ine-webapp::apache]"] from CLI options
   [2017-07-19T15:59:00+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[apt], recipe[ine-webapp::apache]]
   [2017-07-19T15:59:00+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[apt], recipe[ine-webapp::apache]]
   [2017-07-19T15:59:00+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [apt, ine-webapp::apache]
   [2017-07-19T15:59:00+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [apt, ine-webapp::apache]
   [2017-07-19T15:59:00+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for server-ubuntu-1604
   [2017-07-19T15:59:00+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for server-ubuntu-1604
   [2017-07-19T15:59:00+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
   [2017-07-19T15:59:00+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
   [2017-07-19T15:59:00+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
   [2017-07-19T15:59:00+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
   resolving cookbooks for run list: ["apt", "ine-webapp::apache"]
```

There is only one instance in my kitchen list

```
    chef-repo/cookbooks/ine-webapp$ kitchen list
    Instance            Driver   Provisioner  Verifier  Transport  Last Action  Last Error
    server-ubuntu-1604  Vagrant  ChefZero     Inspec    Ssh        Converged    <None>
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what causes the double logging yet, just that it appears to not be consistent enough to debug :( If you can come up with a minimal repro case, please let us know. Otherwise it seems to just go away sometimes.